# ToolBar always raised Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design

I want to extend my application toolbar, but it does not seem to work correctly.
[image]

My code is this:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        >
    <TextView
        android:text="Remplissez le formulaire pour signaler un probléme dans votre batîment"
        android:layout_width="201dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColorLink="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/textbody"

        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/allLayout"
    android:elevation="20dp"

    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lay"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:weightSum="1">



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditTextEmail"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/feedbackemail"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:layout_width="360dp">
        </EditText>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/nomSite"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="39dp"
            android:prompt="@string/nomdusite"
            android:entries="@array/categories"
            android:hint="Nom du site"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/categories"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="39dp"
            android:prompt="@string/types"
            android:entries="@array/types"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="354dp"
            android:layout_height="136dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="Description*"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:text="Ajouter une photo"
            android:layout_width="316dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:textColorLink="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="addPhoto"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <Button
            android:text="Valider"
            android:layout_width="113dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="sendForm"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see in the picture, some part of the toolbar has more elevation than the rest. How do i fix it?

Comment: Use CoordinateLayout  http://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout

Comment: You don't have a `Toolbar` in your layout. It should be a child of `AppBarLayout` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html

Comment: Try with getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0); in your onCreate() method

Comment: it works! thank you.

Comment: I have added as formal answer, please accept it. Maybe could help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0); in your onCreate() method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_your_layout);
    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
}
```

Comment: Whilst this may work for you in this instance, what you are doing is incorrect. You are using the built in ActionBar from the Activity and an AppBarLayout. You actually need to use a NoActionBar Theme and then add a toolbar to your AppBarLayout. Essentially your AppBarLayout is below the ActionBar which is why it casts a shadow. The toolbar should be inside the AppBarLayout especially if you intend to use any of the scrolling behaviours.

Answer (score 1):

try to add this properties to appbarlayout tag in xml

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"   
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
```